# (net use) What is better- UNC path or map drive?

Tags: java, mount, net-use

I am writing a java application which iterates over all the files in a network share and searches the files for some keywords.
I am aware I can use the smbj library, but I want to use native windows/linux mounting.

I am using the `net use` command on windows and `mount -t` command on linux.

> **Is there any difference in mapping the drive to a drive letter?**

(So that I can avoid the code to wait if no drive letter is available)

Obviously, I don't need the drive letter for the user, I am unmounting the drive at the end of my code.

> Does mapping the drive make further calls to the drive faster?
> (X:/Folder vs \Share\Folder)

Comment: i can imagin mapped one is faster since it should preload something. but you'd better do some benchmark.

Comment: I couldn't any evidence to support this. In my testing, both perform the same.

Comment: so you got the answer yourself.

Comment: Well.. cant say so! I am not aware if I am missing any network related scenarios.. (Network load, etc)